# preg_replace() no me funciona

Tags: php, php7

estoy intentando eliminar todos los caracteres excepto numeros y letras pero no me funciona

```
public function number10($valor){
        $nueva = preg_replace('[^ A-Za-z0-9_-ñÑ]', '', $valor);
        echo $nueva;
        return $nueva;
        /*if($tamañoCadena == 10){
            return $tamañoCadena;
        }else{
            return 'No Válida';
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Dices que no te funciona, ¿qué resultado te esta devolviendo?

Comment: lo mismo que ingreso en el input

Comment: no me reemplaza nada exactamente lo que ingreso me retorna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que

- Las expresiones regulares van entre diagonales `/`
- Tu expresión regular solo debería tener esto: `A-Za-z0-9` para indicar todos los grupos de valores que formarían parte del patrón a encontrar
- Es correcto utilizar el símbolo de `^` dentro de los corchetes para indicar que todo lo que coincida con esos grupos de valores es lo que será negado

Código:

```
function number10($valor){
        $nueva = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $valor);
        return $nueva;
    }

echo number10("h*la-123");
```

Con una salida como esta:

> hla123

**Referencias**

- [preg_replace en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: te lo agradezco mucho tenia rato buscando voy a leer mas de las expresiones regulares es que me urge mucho terminarlo muchas gracias